# Equivalence relations and norms on topological vector spaces exercise

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $E,||.||$ be a Banach space. If $F$ is a closed subspace of $E$.
>   Consider the quotient space $E_{|F}$ the quotient space of $E$ by $F$ such that:
>
> $x,y\in E\:\:\implies x\sim y\implies x-y\in F$ is an equivalence relation.
>
> Prove that function:
>
> $[x]\to||[x]||=\inf_{y\in F}||x-y||$ is a well defined norm on the quotient space.

I do not understand ||[x]||.  $||[x]||=\inf_{y\in F}||x-y||=?$

**Question:**

I am not understanding this exercise. How should I prove the ||.|| is a norm? I know the norm is the distance of x to $F$. How should I write that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you just have a new norm $||[x]||$ which is defined to be $\inf_{y\in F}||x-y||$. where $||x-y||$ is the norm of E, the given banach space. so just prove the norm axioms for $ \inf_{y\in F}||x-y||$ are fulfilled for the equivalence classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing here is to understand the definitions. We define an equivalence relation on $E$: $x\sim y\iff x-y\in F$. Then for any $x\in E$ we can define its equivalence class:

$[x]=\{y\in E: x-y\in F\}=\{x+f: f\in F\}=x+F$

And now the quotient space $E/F$ is the space of all equivalence classes with the operations defined in the most natural way: $[x+y]=[x]+[y]$ and $[\lambda x]=\lambda[x]$. The operations are well defined, so $E/F$ is a vector space. And now we can define a norm on it like this:

$||[x]||=\inf_{y\in F}||x-y||=\inf_{y\in F}||x+y||=\inf_{z\in [x]}||z||$

So all you have to prove is that this is really a norm. I'll give an example. Obviously the function we defined is always non negative. Now why $||[x]||=0$ if and only if $[x]=[0]$? Suppose $||[x]||=0$. By the definition of infimum we can take a sequence of vectors $y_n\in F$ such that $||x-y_n||\to ||[x]||=0$. That implies $y_n\to x$ as vectors. But since $F$ is a closed subspace we conclude that $x\in F$, which means $[x]=[0]$. So we have that property. Now try to prove the other properties of norm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not clear to me the following:$||[x]||=\inf_{y\in F}||x-y||=\inf_{y\in F}||x+y||=\inf_{z\in [x]}||z||$ It is true that $x\sim y$ if x-y=f\in F such that $x=f+y$ not necessarily $||x+y||$.How did you get $\inf_{y\in F}||x-y||=\inf_{y\in F}||x+y||$?

Comment: Since $F$ is a vector space we know that $f∈F$ if and only if $(−f)∈F$. So taking all the vectors of the form $x−f$ when $f∈F$ and taking all the vectors of the form $x+f$ when $f∈F$ is the same thing, both are just the set $x+F$. In other words we take the infimum on the set of norms of all vectors which are equivalent to $x$. The easiest way to think of an equivalence class is like this: $[x]=x+F=\{x+f:f∈F\}$. It is easy to see that this is exactly the set of vectors which are equivalent to $x$ by the relation we defined.

Answer (score 1):

$\|[x]+[x']\| =\|[x+x']\|\leq \|x+x'-y-y'\|$ for all $y, y' \in F$ [because $y+y' \in F$]. Hence $\|[x]+[x']\| \leq \|x-y\|+ \|x'-y'\|$. Take infimum over all $y \in F$ and all $y' \in F$ to get triangle inequality. Also $\|[x]\|=0$ implies there is a sequence $(y_n) \in F$ such that $\|x-y_n\| \to 0$. Since $y_n$'s belong to $F$ and $F$ is closed, $x =\lim y_n \in F$ and this makes $[x]=[0]$, the zero element of $E_{|F}$.